# Remove invalid/incorrectly placed tags from html string

Tags: c#, html, string

I'm wondering if there is a good (or good enough) way to remove invalid or incorrectly placed HTML tags from an HTML string in C#?

Example 1: `<div> </div> </div>` should be changed to `<div> </div>`

Example 2: `<div> </section> </div>` should be changed to `<div> </div>`

Basically the transformed html string should be W3C validated markup. I understand that this may be a bit difficult to do, perhaps there is a library that does the job well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using HTMLTidy.

Since you're using C#, there's the tidy.net project.  I think there are dlls that you can just reference and use in your C# code.

Or, you can just use the command line stuff for HTMLTidy.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I found the .NET wrapper for Tidy here: https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged. The up-to-date repository of this library is found here: https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5. I remember ending up solving the root issue that generated the invalid HTML string rather than cleaning it up in the end :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing the root issue that generated an invalid HTML string. In such a scenario, it is exceedingly better to fix the main problem - if possible - than the symptoms.